# Mysql or PHP not converting quotes correctly

Tags: php, mysql, quotes, mysql-real-escape-string

I have a textarea where users enter some information. Some users enter single and double quotes in their information and what i end up seeing in the page is â�� and all types of weird characters where single/double quotes are suppose to be. I simply use the function mysqli_real_escape_string() and trim() to store the information and htmleneties() to display them in php.

I my database I already see the â�� characters so why the single/double quotes are property stored? Thanks!

Comment: What's the encoding of the database? What's the encoding of the output HTML?

Comment: encoding of db is MySQL charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8) and i have this in my html <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inconsistent character sets. Make sure the same character set is used on the database, the database connection, the database table, the table column, the content-type header used when serving the page, and the content-type meta tag of the page. You also want to avoid using PHP string functions on multibyte encodings as they're only safe for iso-8859-1 encoded text. If you plan to accept and display languages other than English you should probably be using UTF-8.

Comment: my databse has utf8_general_ci and my html has <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />. Should be the same right?

Comment: `utf8_general_ci` is a collation, not a character set. You're looking at the wrong thing.

Answer (score 0):

- Be sure you have utf8 encoding in DB
- Be sure you set names

---

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
```

---

- be sure you set charset in php

---

```
header("Content-type: text/html;charset: utf-8");
```

Comment: im looking at phpmyadmin right now, there is a bunch of utf8: utf8_unicode_ci, utf8_general_ci, etc. Which one should i choose?

Comment: Collation wouldn't affect the actual content, just things like sorting. I think you mean encoding.

Comment: the collation for the individual tables are latin1_swedish_ci, may be the problem? How do i change the encoding in phpmyadmin?